# ada get_line of arrays (1..5) of string(1..10)

Tags: arrays, loops, ada, getline

I have a problem.
I have made an array of string because I want to store some names in an array.
The problem is, when I write name shorter the 10 characters, the program fill the array with random characters up to 10. And I don't know how to solve this.  I have tried with `Ada.Text_IO.Skip_Line` but it still don't work as I want to. 
(The problem is from an exam where we were suppose to store 5 names on revolvers :)..)

This is the code

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO; use Ada.Integer_Text_IO;

procedure Revolver is

   type Pistol is array (1..5) of String(1..10);

   procedure Get_namn(Namn: out  Pistol) is
      X:Integer;
      pist:String(1..10);
   begin
      New_Line;
      for I in 1..5 loop
         Get_line(Pist,x);
         if pist'Last=x then
            Skip_Line;
         end if;

         Namn(I):= Pist;
      end loop;

      New_Line;
   end Get_Namn; 

   procedure Put_Namn(Namn: in Pistol) is
   begin
      for I in Namn'range loop
         Put(Namn(I));
         New_Line;
      end loop;
   end Put_Namn;

   Namn : Pistol;
   X    : Integer;
begin
   Put("Mata in revolvrar: ");
   Get_namn(Namn);
   Put_Namn(Namn);
end Revolver;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could solve the problem by initialising the strings by filling them with space characters. - Except that `Get_Line` is specified as having `Item` as an `out` parameter. - Sticking to space-padded fixed-length strings:

```ada
declare
   Buffer    : String (1 .. 20);
   Filled_To : Natural;
begin
   Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line (Item => Buffer,
                         Last => Filled_To);
   Buffer (Filled_To + 1 .. Buffer'Last) := (others => ' ');
end;
```

Another option is to keep track of the actual lengths, and only show that much, when you print out the names again.

A third option is to use Ada.Strings.Bounded, which handles the keeping track of the length for you.

A fourth option is to use Ada.Strings.Unbounded, which uses dynamic allocation to adjust the length of the stored string according to your needs.

Which of the four solutions is the proper one is not clear from your problem description, but the first one is the easiest to implement.

Comment: Thank you! But how do I fill the array with space characters?

Comment: I don’t believe that "filling [...] with space characters" can be relied on. [ARM A.7.1(19)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-10-7.html#p19) says at the end of the para "The values of characters not assigned are not specified."

Comment: To fill with spaces, look at Move procedure for Fixed String [ARM A.4.3(7)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-4-3.html)

Comment: @LouiseHjalmarson I have extended the answer with a bit of code, which ensures that you have spaces in the remaining part of the fixed-length string you read the line into.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what you're seeing is the result of your type-definition:

```
 type Pistol is array (1..5) of String(1..10);
```

See, you're declaring an array of five elements which are strings of length 10.

Someone's already mentioned the bounded and unbounded strings, but perhaps you should look at `Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Holders`, instantiate it with `String` and make your array-elements of that container.